# iOS how to manage Deep links with HTTP via Safari ?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, deep-linking

i know i can manage like this "totoapp:example.com/member" via URL with Safari. 
My app can capture this with RemoteNotification in AppDelegate.

But, my problem, i cant capture "http://example.com/member" via Safari. 
How to deal with "http" for deep linking ?

i wanted to capture "http" with this URL : "http://www.example.ca/?section=about&lang=en" and my app will open at "About us" screen and switch to English language.

Any1 got a very simple tutorial to do this easily ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are **Universal Links**, which Apple introduced in iOS9. Please refer to the Apple [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) to see how to implement them.